# qt [ OpenGL ] not working on android

Tags: android, c++, qt, opengl-es

I am working in Qt with OpenGL.

I wrote some code which compiled and ran on Desktop Qt. When I tried to compile the code on Android I got an error saying that the OpenGL libraries were not declared.

What is the problem?

Errors:-
[image]

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGLFunctions>
#include <QGLWidget>

class app: public QGLWidget, QGLFunctions{
  public:
   void  initializeGL();
   void  paintGL();
   void  resizeGL();

};

void app::initializeGL(){
    qglClearColor(Qt::black);
}
void app::resizeGL(){
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glViewport(0,0,(GLint)200,(GLint)200);
    glOrtho(0,100,100,0,-1,1);
}
void app::paintGL(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(1,0,0);
        glVertex2f(0,100);

        glColor3f(0,1,0);
        glVertex2f(100,100);

        glColor3f(0,0,1);
        glVertex2f(100,0);

        glColor3f(1,1,1);
        glVertex2f(0,0);

    glEnd();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    app App;
    App.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Not sure what "compile on Android" means... but it really doesn't matter.  That code is not an Android app and it won't work without significant further porting.

Comment: You're missing includes for OpenGL headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-compiled Windows desktop version before of Qt5 5.0.2 is built against ANGLE which only provides OpenGL ES 2 support by implementing it on top of DirectX 9. OpenGL ES 2 does not support the legacy fixed function pipeline, only a shader-based one.

After some time of searching I found the closed bugreport in Qt bugtrecker:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28715

Looks like you need to build your own copy of Qt 5 to use the native OpenGL drivers by passing in "-opengl desktop" to configure. With the 2nd option you should have access to OpenGL from 1.0 up to 4.3 (if your card/driver support it), or just do not use the legacy fixed function pipeline, use only a shader-based one.